# AVD issue while opening through terminal

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I was trying to fire `emulator` command from terminal to run an emulator but came across some Android SDK path issue.  After some research I updated the images through SDK manager and tweaked some SDK path location and emulator started running from `AVD Manager`.

I can run emulators from within AVD Manager ONLY but the very same android emulator fails to run if started from terminal. 
It generates an error which states following:

`PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

What am I doing wrong ? Is there any another path that I need to set ? 
Please help.

Comment: Check this link to set SDK related path's in Windows . http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/09/set-androidhome-and-path-environment.html  . If this still not resolves the problem, then create variable in Environment Variables name it as ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set C:/users/<username>/.android  as the value

Comment: Setting ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (not HOME) to that value changes the error message to: `PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:/users/username/.android]!`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Set ANDROID_SDK_HOME it will work perfectly